# JavaScript: manipulate two Arrays

Tags: javascript

I am just starting on JavaScript and getting lost on how to deal with this issue.

Here's the problem:

Five people, John, Ed, Sam, Alex and Mark are 16, 25, 18, 30 and 27 years old respectively.

I want to use arrays and functions to output the youngest and oldest of the five.

I tried to form two arrays i.e.

```
var Name = ['John', 'Ed', 'Sam', 'Alex', 'Mark']; 
var Age =  [16, 25, 18, 30, 27];
```

I am finding it difficult to manipulate these arrays to get the required results.

What do I do to these arrays so that it can print for instance, that the youngest person is John and the oldest is Alex?

Comment: Be aware that the convention (in JavaScript) is to start variable names with a lowercase letter. Names starting with capitals are usually reserved for [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use array of objects - eg.

```
var People = [{ name : 'John', age : 16 }, .... ]
```

So you can keep age and name together. Then use sort function with custom sorting function

```
var PeopleSorted = People.sort( function( a, b ) { return a.age - b.age; });
```

PS. More on Array.sort here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: A good answer, though you may want to consider providing a link to a more reputable source than W3Schools - see [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) for information on why it's bad - such as the Mozilla Developer Network ([sort - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

Comment: @Raynos +1 for restructuring the data. Such structure is much more natural.

Comment: @Raynos - this is structure you get from any DB - so why do two additional steps ? ( put data it separate arrays and then assemble it )

Comment: In this context I think restructuring is fine since the OP obviously wrote some trivial code that is easily changed to this. Otherwise you would have to add code to transform those arrays into the object array before sorting. Also, don't start the variable names with capital case please.

Comment: +1, @Raynos: From the question it's obvious that the OP has a conceptual problem that is in want of a solution; how to "use arrays and functions" to solve the issue of sorting people and their respective ages. The OP states that the current structure is problematic, given this, the solution **is** showing the OP how to properly format data to facilitate solving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't normally have data structured that way as you can see
it's excessively complicated to do anything with it.

```
var names = ['John', 'Ed', 'Sam', 'Alex', 'Mark']; 
var ages =  [16, 25, 18, 30, 27];
```

If in some hypothetical situation you actually had to work with that, you could normalize it this way:

```
var people = names.map(function (name, i) {
    return {
        name: name,
        age: this[i]
    };
}, ages);
```

The result of the mapping is same as writing:

```
var people = [  
    {"name":"John","age":16},
    {"name":"Ed","age":25},
    {"name":"Sam","age":18},
    {"name":"Alex","age":30},
    {"name":"Mark","age":27} 
];
```

(Yes, the property names are quoted because I cheesed it with `JSON.stringify` cos I'm lazy )

And sorting becomes really trivial:

```
people.sort( function( a, b ) { return a.age - b.age; });

var youngestName = people[0].name,
    oldestName = people[people.length-1].name;
```

So if you have control, use proper structure in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = ['John', 'Ed', 'Sam', 'Alex', 'Mark'],
    ages =  [16, 25, 18, 30, 27];

// reduce the ages array to an object containing youngest and oldest
var data = ages.reduce(function (memo, age, index) {
   // for every member in the age array
   // if the age is less then the youngest
   if (age < memo.youngest.age) {
       // then set that to be the youngest age
       memo.youngest.age = age;
       // and store the name by grabbing it from the names array by index
       memo.youngest.name = names[index];
   }
   // do the same for oldest
   if (age > memo.oldest.age) {
       memo.oldest.age = age;
       memo.oldest.name = names[index];
   }
   return memo;
// create a default seed for this object, 
// the default youngest age is infinite, the default oldest age is minus infinite
}, {
  youngest: {
    age: Infinity
  },
  oldest: {
    age: -Infinity
  }
});

// data object returned has the same format as the initial seed object
console.log(data.youngest.name);
console.log(data.oldest.name);
```

Comment: Thanks. but this is a bit complex for a beginner...:)

Comment: @user1149232 That's the wrong attitude to take when programming. You shouldn't say "Oh, that's hard, I don't want to learn anything." You need to ask people *right now* about the things you've tried to understand but are "too hard" for a beginner.

Comment: @Incognito, Thanks for the advice. I only meant to say that it'll help to get the basics right rather than cutting corners to advanced procedures.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Name = ['John', 'Ed', 'Sam', 'Alex', 'Mark'];
var Age = [16, 25, 18, 30, 27];
var AgeFromName = {};
for (var i = 0; i < Age.length; i++) {
    AgeFromName[Age[i]] = Name[i];
}
Age.sort();
alert(AgeFromName[Age[0]]);
```

Comment: @Raynos - looks like `AgeFromName` is an object with the ages as keys, so it will work as shown in the question.

Comment: @Raynos: `AgeFromName[0]` is what's undefined.  `AgeFromName` is an age->name mapping.  (So really it ought to be called `nameFromAge` or `ageToName`, but eh.)  The point is, sort the Age array, then find the name corresponding to the lowest age.

Comment: Yes it does. Am wondering why there's no need for a function in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects, where each object has a `name` and `age` property, which would allow you to sort the array by age and thus easily get the youngest or oldest. This is covered by at least one other answer, so I won't repeat it here.

Since you mention you are just starting in JavaScript you might like some general practice looping through arrays and so forth, so for the two arrays you defined in your question if you want the youngest person then loop through the age array to find the location of the lowest age and then output the name from the corresponding location in the name array:

```
function getYoungest(names, ages) {
   if (names.length != ages.length || names.length === 0)
       return ""; // stop if arrays were a different length or empty

   var i,
       y,
       a = Number.MAX_VALUE;

   for (i=0; i < ages.length; i++) {
      if (ages[i] < a) {
         a = ages[i];
         y = names[i];
      }
   }
   return y;
}

var Name = ['John', 'Ed', 'Sam', 'Alex', 'Mark'],
    Age =  [16, 25, 18, 30, 27];

console.log(getYoungest(Name, Age)); // 'John'
```

The above uses `a` to keep track of the lowest age so far, and `y` to keep the name that goes with that age, but of course you could add additional variables to simultaneously keep track of the highest age and corresponding name so far so that you could output the youngest and oldest with only one pass through the array.

(Of course something similar to the above would work on an array of objects too, if you didn't want to sort the array, or there was some other criteria you were looking for where sorting wouldn't help.)

Comment: Thanks a million. I am beginning to get the idea. it's still a long way for me before I get the concept fully but this will help an awful lot. Practice, practice, practice...that's just what am doing.

Comment: If you are new to programming (as well as new to JavaScript) it can help to get pencil and paper and work through the code yourself keeping track of what value each variable would have at each step - after a few practices on paper you will learn to do it in your head...

Comment: Yes i am new to programming. I just started this year with java and javascript. Thanks for this useful tip.