# JS new.target vs. instanceof

Tags: javascript, new-operator, instanceof

So I have done some reading on the `new.target` boolean added in Node 6.x. Here is a simple example of `new.target` provided on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)

```
function Foo() {
  if (!new.target) throw "Foo() must be called with new";
  console.log("Foo instantiated with new");
}

Foo(); // throws "Foo() must be called with new"
new Foo(); // logs "Foo instantiated with new"
```

But this reads a lot like what I am presently using the below code for

```
var Foo = function (options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
    return new Foo(options);
  }

  // do stuff here
}
```

My question is this: Is there any benifit to `new.target` over the instance of method? I don't particularly see either as more clear. `new.target` may be a scosche easier to read but only because it has one less set of parens `()`.

Can anyone provide an insight I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: You can call a constructor on any instance, but you could call it without `new`.

Comment: `new.target` is not a boolean! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572) for more explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Bergi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **this instanceof Foo** you will check if this instance is a Foo, but you can't ensure that was called with a **new**.
I can just do a thing like this

```
var foo = new Foo("Test");
var notAFoo = Foo.call(foo, "AnotherWord");
```

And will work fine. Using **new.target** you can avoid this issues.
I suggest you to read this book https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read

Comment: Even better: `foo.constructor("AnotherWord")`

Comment: @Bergi Are you sure your this way will work ? object cant access constructor like this but only the prototype can. I mean if 'foo' is the prototype then only your mentioned code will work

Comment: @Sumer Yes, it will work - the `foo` object *inherits* from the prototype so you can access the `.constructor` property on it.