# How is class extends handled in non-ES6 Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It is [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713/are-es6-classes-just-syntactic-sugar-for-the-prototypal-pattern-in-javascript/36419728) that the ES6 `class` keyword is just [syntactic sugar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for Javascript's prototype-based inheritance system. This is obvious to see with one exception: the `extends` keyword. For example:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(){
        this.sayHello = () => console.log('Hello')
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor(){
        super(); 
        this.sayGoodbye = () => console.log('Goodbye');
    }
}
```

If `class` is just syntactic sugar, what is happening under the hood here? Is there a standard < ES6 design pattern that simulates class inheritance being invoked, or is this some new functionality?

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#classes

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47671709/1491895) in the referenced question talks about what `extends` does.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a standard < ES6 design pattern that simulates class inheritance being invoked?

JavaScript has a prototype inheritance model, which is also what you get with the `class` keyword. Your code is approximately equivalent to:

```
function Foo () {
    this.sayHello = () => console.log('Hello')
}

function Bar () {
    // super();
    Foo.call( this );

    this.sayGoodbye = () => console.log('Goodbye');
}

// extends
Bar.prototype = Object.create( Foo.prototype );
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

Answer (score -1):

> what is happening under the hood here?

That's an implementation detail of the JS engine.

> Is there a standard < ES6 design pattern that simulates class inheritance being invoked

"Standard" is probably going too far, but Babel is a well known transpiler that can convert ES6 to ES5.

It gives this:

```
'use strict';

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Foo = function Foo() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Foo);

    this.sayHello = function () {
        return console.log('Hello');
    };
};

var Bar = function (_Foo) {
    _inherits(Bar, _Foo);

    function Bar() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Bar);

        var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Bar.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Bar)).call(this));

        _this.sayGoodbye = function () {
            return console.log('Goodbye');
        };
        return _this;
    }

    return Bar;
}(Foo);
```