# What is the difference between prototype-based class syntax and class syntax in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class

Are these interchangeable syntaxes to create a JS class?  I'm used to the  `class` syntax but don't understand the differences between them exactly.

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

User.prototype.sayHi = function() {
  alert(this.name);
}

let user = new User("John");
user.sayHi();
```

vs.

```
class User {

 constructor(name) {
   this.name = name;
 }

 sayHi() {
   alert(this.name);
 }

}

let user = new User("John");
user.sayHi();
```

Comment: Yes, what you've posted is the same - `class` is just syntax sugar on top of the `function` version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are es6 classes just syntactic sugar for the prototypal pattern in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36419713/1048572)

Answer (score 20):

The main differences between classes and constructor functions are:

- Classes can’t be called without `new`, but functions intended as constructors can (and their `this` will be wrong)

  ```js
  'use strict';

  function Foo() {
      console.log(this);
  }

  class Bar {
      constructor() {
          console.log(this);
      }
  }

  Foo();
  Bar();
  ```
- Classes can extend more types than constructors can (like functions and arrays)

  ```js
  'use strict';

  function Foo(body) {
      Function.call(this, body);
  }

  Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo, Function);
  Foo.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);

  class Bar extends Function {}

  (new Bar('console.log(1)'))();
  (new Foo('console.log(1)'))();
  ```
- Classes’ prototypes are their parents (they inherit static properties); writers of constructor functions usually don’t bother with this
- Non-classes can’t extend classes (because they can’t call the parent constructor – see the first point)

  ```js
  'use strict';

  class Bar extends Function {}

  function Foo() {
      Bar.call(this);
  }

  Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo, Bar);
  Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype);

  void new Foo();
  ```

  (although you can hack an approximate equivalent by creating an object with [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct), using it instead of `this`, and returning it – but I’m not sure why you ever would, since `Reflect.construct` can’t be polyfilled)

Classes are also scoped like `let`/`const` (block scope, temporal dead zone, not redeclareable) rather than like `var` (function scope, hoisted) or like function declarations (it’s complicated).

In your example, an additional difference is that `sayHi` is defined by assigning to a new property instead of with e.g. `Object.defineProperty`, so the property’s properties differ from those in the class example in that `sayHi` is enumerable in the former but not the latter.

```js
function UserA(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

UserA.prototype.sayHi = function () {
    alert(this.name);
};

class UserB {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayHi() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

let a = [];
let b = [];

for (let key in new UserA()) a.push(key);
for (let key in new UserB()) b.push(key);

console.log(a, b);
```

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript.

You can use a tool like the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to see how the ES6, class-based code you have above is then transpiled into ES5, prototype-based code:

### ES6 Class

```
class User {

 constructor(name) {
   this.name = name;
 }

 sayHi() {
   alert(this.name);
 }

}

let user = new User("John");
user.sayHi();
```

### Transpiled to ES5

```
"use strict";

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var User = function () {
  function User(name) {
    _classCallCheck(this, User);

    this.name = name;
  }

  _createClass(User, [{
    key: "sayHi",
    value: function sayHi() {
      alert(this.name);
    }
  }]);

  return User;
}();

var user = new User("John");
user.sayHi();
```

All ES6+ functionality will be able to be transpiled into ES5-- it is all, effectively, syntactic sugar.  All "new features" can still be achieved in ES5.  This is called, I believe, the "One JavaScript" doctrine.

Comment: *“All ES6+ functionality will be able to be transpiled into ES5-- it is all, effectively, syntactic sugar. All "new features" can still be achieved in ES5.”* This isn’t true. Many parts of ES6 classes can’t be replicated in ES5; Babel just makes its best effort.