# Why do classes and functions behave differently in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My understanding was that all classes were essentially functions, and all instances were essentially objects. But something confused me.

```js
//Take this for example:

    function AnimalFunc(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sayName = function() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    }

//And compare it with this:

    class AnimalClass {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        sayName() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    }

//Now I instantiate them.

    cat = new AnimalFunc("cat")
    cat.sayName() // -> "cat"
    dog = new AnimalClass("dog")
    dog.sayName() // -> "dog"
    
    console.log(Object.keys(cat));
    console.log(Object.keys(dog));
```

**Expected Observations:**

1. `typeof(AnimalClass)` and `typeof(AnimalFunc)` both return `function`.
2. `typeof(cat)` and `typeof(dog)` both return `object`.

**Unexpected Observations:**

1. If I do `Object.keys(cat)`, I get `["name","sayname"]`.
2. But if I do `Object.keys(dog)`, I get `["name"]`.

My question is: why do I not get `sayname` as a key for the class instance? Why do I get it only for the function instance?

Comment: `Object.keys` only returns *own properties*. Putting methods on `this` in the constructor instead of on the prototype is kind of just wrong. For a comparison of constructors making use of prototypes and the `class` syntax for defining them, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643582/what-is-the-difference-between-prototype-based-class-syntax-and-class-syntax-in/49643668#49643668

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example, with a function, creates a new function property when creating an instance, and therefore, a new key for `Object.keys` to pick up.

The second example, with a class, assigns the function property to the object's `prototype` instead. Because of this, a new key isn't actually created, and the `sayName` function will be found by walking up the prototype chain.

You can replicate the class behavior by doing this:

```
function AnimalFunc(name) {
  this.name = name
}

AnimalFunc.prototype.sayName = function () {
  console.log(this.name)
}
```

[Here's some reading if you want to familiarize yourself with JS's prototype model.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) Can find more articles and such by searching up "javascript prototype", if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have declared two properties named `name` and `sayname`

```
this.name;
this.sayname;
```

In the class `AnimalClass` you only declared as property the key `name` within the constructor body:

```
this.name = ....
```

> Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually.

So, basically will return the properties directly declared using the context `this`.

## Example with class

- Declaration of the function within the constructor's body

```js
class AnimalClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // This is just to illustrate!
    this.sayName = function() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(new AnimalClass('Dog')))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because **AnimalClass**'s `sayName` is in **AnimalClass**'s prototype, whereas **AnimalFunc**'s `sayName` is not, it's part of the instance (`this`).

In the case of **AnimalClass**, there is only one `sayName` function that all instances share a reference to:

```js
class AnimalClass {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var a = new AnimalClass("a"), b = new AnimalClass("b");

a.sayName === b.sayName; // true
```

Where as each of **AnimalFunc** instances has its own definition of `sayName`, because it is re-defined in the constructor for each instance:

```js
function AnimalFunc(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sayname = function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

var a = new AnimalFunc("a"), b = new AnimalFunc("b");

a.sayName === b.sayName; // false
```

The eqivalent of your **AnimalClass** using `function` is:

```
function AnimalFunc(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

AnimalFunc.prototype.sayname = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

And the equivalent of your **AnimalFunc** using `class` is:

```
class AnimalClass {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sayName = function() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    }
}
```