# Inheritance and the prototype chain in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have the following classes

```
class Polygon {
   constructor(height, width) {
      this.height = height;
      this.width = width;
   }
}



class Square extends Polygon {
   constructor(sideLength) {
      super(sideLength, sideLength);
   }

   area() {
      return this.height * this.width;
   }

   sideLength(newLength) {
      this.height = newLength;
      this.width = newLength;
   }
}
```

and thei I create an instance of the class `Square`

```
var square = new Square(2);
```

My expectations were to find in the square object (directly in it and not in its prototype) the `area` and `sideLength` methods. Differently I find them in the `__proto__` object.
[image: result]

I don't understand why it happens.
Could you "translate" this same code using a constructor rather than a class? Maybe I will more easily get the point in this way...

Comment: That's one of the points of having classes - to have objects share a common single internal prototype object (here, `Square.prototype`, which is the same as `square.__proto__` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(square)`) - rather than every new object having its own methods

Comment: ES6 still uses prototype chaining, classes are just syntactically sugar. Edit: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713/are-es6-classes-just-syntactic-sugar-for-the-prototypal-pattern-in-javascript for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method defined in the class are transformed as protoType method in order for all instances of the class to share the same method. A functional component version of your case would be

```
function Polygon(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}


function Square(sideLength){
   Polygon.call(this, sideLength);
}

Square.prototype.area = function() {
   return this.height * this.width;
}

Square.prototype.sideLength(newLength) {
  this.height = newLength;
  this.width = newLength;
}
```

However if you define the function in the class constructor or using `arrow functions` they would belong to the class instance like

```js
class Polygon {
   constructor(height, width) {
      this.height = height;
      this.width = width;
   }
}



class Square extends Polygon {
   constructor(sideLength) {
      super(sideLength, sideLength);
      this.getArea = function() {
         return this.height * this.width;
      }
      this.sideLengthWithBind = this.sideLength.bind(this);
   }

   area =() =>{
      return this.height * this.width;
   }

   sideLength(newLength) {
      this.height = newLength;
      this.width = newLength;
   }
}

const square = new Square(5);

console.log(square);
```

Comment: So, am I wrong if I said that *every* function defined inside a class becomes part of the prototype object of the instances created with that class?

Comment: Yes, unless the function is defined inside the class constructor like `this.getArea = function() {
         return this.height * this.width;
      }` or using arrow function like `area = () => {}`

Comment: oh, this is a very important clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Class properties are not restricted to arrow functions. `area = function() {}` or `area = 42;` would also create `area` on the object itself.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, you are right, the question was not about class properties and hence didn't add that detail here

Comment: I was just referring to your comment.