# Why the constructor of a random class equals the native Function object?

Tags: javascript, constructor, es6-class

Why the following code returns `true`?

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(a, b) { }
}

console.log(MyClass.constructor === Function);
```

According to this question: [are es6 classes just syntactic sugar for the prototypal pattern in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713) a `class` is a `function` which is filled with the `constructor`'s body at runtime, which might explain the behavior above, but I still don't understand it very well. Can someone explain?

Comment: `MyClass` is a function itself and its type is...`MyClass`. But the thing that generate that function is not a different *custom* function.

Comment: all class constructors extend `Function`, and all class instances extend `Object`. This means that classes are actually themselves instances of `Function`

Comment: I think you might be misinterpreting stuff here - `MyClass.constructor` is NOT the `constructor` in your `class MyClass` - `MyClass` itself *is* the constructor. If you call `new MyClass("alpha", "beta")` you are going to execute the code inside `constructor`.

Comment: @VLAZ `s/call/construct/`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts just trying to avoid [semantic satiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation) but you're correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [are es6 classes just syntactic sugar for the prototypal pattern in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713/are-es6-classes-just-syntactic-sugar-for-the-prototypal-pattern-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `constructor` property of any kind of JavaScript object is actually what has been used to construct it:

A `class` is actually a `function`, so it is constructed from `Function`. That's why `MyClass.constructor === Function`

The `constructor` of a `class` is actually the `class` itself. It is also located at `MyClass.prototype.constructor` to make it available from the `constructor` property of an instance. Indeed, `MyClass === MyClass.prototype.constructor`

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is just a **function** to create custom object type and create object’s instances using `new` keyword.

```
 /**
 * `Constructor function` that defines custom data object, commonly named using capital letter.
 * The properties will be available for every object created from this function,
 * because `this` points to the instance of the object.
 */

function Human(name, lastName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = name;
}

/**
 * Objects are created from `constructor function` using `new` keyword.
 * Parameters that are passed to the function will be the values of object's properties.
 */
const american = new Human('Mike', 'Brown');
```

Inside classes the `constructor` method is actually constructor function - what creates instances of an object.

```
class AnotherHuman{
    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

const student = AnotherHuman('Jack', 22);
```