# Having variables in the constructor vs in the actual class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

The first of the below code examples is what I am doing today, where I initialise the global variables in the constructor.

But would there be any harm in moving the global variables out in the class, as seen in the second example?

```
class Alert {
  constructor(alert) {
    this.load = JSON.parse('{}');
    this.alert = alert;
    this.#coolDownTime = 0;
  };

  #coolDownTime;
}
```

vs just doing

```
class Alert {
  constructor(alert) {
    this.alert = alert;
  };

  #coolDownTime = 0;
  #load = JSON.parse('{}');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript classes are functions, which are objects. (`POOP` (prototype object-oriented programming)).

Here's an interesting concept, since JavaScript classes are functions, then what do we actually write? JavaScript ES6 classes are just syntactic sugar for prototypes. **This means, that both of your ideas are actually the same.** 
 This is exactly how creating a method works.

Here is a good reference:
[Are ES6 classes just syntactic sugar for the prototypal pattern in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713/are-es6-classes-just-syntactic-sugar-for-the-prototypal-pattern-in-javascript)