# Using call() method vs setting prototype property for inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm a somewhat beginner, I used to know the very basics but stopped programming after that.

In JavaScript's Prototypal Inheritance, I've found/learned two ways of doing this.

Using the `prototype` property of a constructor:

```
function Mammal(name) {
    this.name = name,
    this.order = "Mammal",

    this.sayHi = function() {
        console.log("My name is " + this.name);
    }
}

function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = "Felidae";
}

Cat.prototype = new Mammal();

let lion = new Cat("Lion");
```

Or by calling the `Mammal.call(this, name)` method.

What are the differences between the two results? Which one is to be preferred if they're different?

Comment: Neither one is to be preferred; a combination of the two is closer to the correct version, which is `Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);`, `Mammal.call(this, name);` in `Cat`, and putting `sayHi` on `Mammal.prototype`. Better, use a class, which does all this and also improves other behaviours. `class Cat extends Mammal {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we use `class` keyword to define a class in many program languages. In `Javascript` you can define your classes using simple and clear syntax using `class` keyword.

Either you can use the two ways you mentioned, you can use `class` keyword:

```js
class Mammal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = 'Mammal';
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
  }
}

class Cat extends Mammal {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.family = 'Felidae';
  }
}

let lion = new Cat('Lion');

lion.sayHi();
```

Read more about classes on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) or [W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

Comment: If the `class` keyword is just synctactical sugar, which method is it using under the hood, `call()` or `property` ?

Comment: @Kaiser  *"syntactical sugar"* is not correct properly at all, there are many sources you can read 
 about this misleading keyword: https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/debunking-fake-classes-in-javascript-78f67a6b5c96 and https://webreflection.medium.com/js-classes-are-not-just-syntactic-sugar-28690fedf078 also read https://javascript.info/class  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713/are-es6-classes-just-syntactic-sugar-for-the-prototypal-pattern-in-javascript/47671709

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks!