# JavaScript - What exactly does the "class" keyword actually do? How is it implemented?

Tags: javascript, function, class, new-operator

I am new to JavaScript and there are some lower level JS concepts I would like to get clarity on. During my learnings I read that "classes are just functions" in JS. This confused me so I tried to do some more reading. (please read it all if you answer)

I came across this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-classes-in-javascript

It draws comparisons between functions and classes, and one of the examples given is as follows:

Function:

```
function Hero(name, level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
}

// Adding a method to the constructor
Hero.prototype.greet = function() {
    return `${this.name} says hello.`;
}
```

Class:

```
class Hero {
    constructor(name, level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }

    // Adding a method to the constructor
    greet() {
        return `${this.name} says hello.`;
    }
}
```

I also came across this description on MDN of what happens when a function is called with the `new` keyword:

> "When *a function* is called with the `new` keyword, *the function*
> **will be used as a constructor**. `new` will do the following things:
>
> 1. Creates a blank, plain JavaScript object. For convenience, let's call it newInstance.
> 2. Points newInstance's [[Prototype]] to the constructor function's prototype property, if the prototype is an Object. Otherwise,
>    newInstance stays as a plain object with Object.prototype as its
>    [[Prototype]].
> 3. Executes the constructor function with the given arguments, binding newInstance as the this context (i.e. all references to this in the
>    constructor function now refer to newInstance).
> 4. If the constructor function returns a non-primitive, this return value becomes the result of the whole new expression. Otherwise, if
>    the constructor function doesn't return anything or returns a
>    primitive, newInstance is returned instead. "

So when we get to step 3. for the first example (where Hero is defined as a function), we will execute the following (*the function* we called the `new` keyword with) as the constructor:

```
function Hero(name, level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }
```

If we apply these exact same steps logic to the second example (where Hero is defined as a class - which we said is a function), once we get to step 3. we are executing the following (*the function* - because we said classes are functions - that we called the `new` keyword with) as the constructor:

```
class Hero {
        constructor(name, level) {
            this.name = name;
            this.level = level;
        }
    
        // Adding a method to the constructor
        greet() {
            return `${this.name} says hello.`;
        }
    }
```

Which to me looks very different. In the former case we are executing lines of code like:

```
this.name = name;
this.level = level;
```

Whereas in the latter we just have some function definitions.

Additionally, the function Hero(name, level) has parameters, whereas the class Hero (which again - we said is a function) does not.

So I am left wondering what exactly the `class` keyword does. I can see that **inside** the Hero class there is a function definition for constructor() - but we don't call *that* with the `new` keyword. We call *Hero* with the `new` keyword.

So if classes are just functions, what exactly do they do, and how do they behave when called with the `new` keyword?

Also if classes are just functions, why is this valid:

```
class Vegetable {
  constructor(type){
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

but this is not:

```
function fruit() {
  constructor(type){
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

Again I am new to JS, and I'm sure there must be some information I am lacking or misunderstanding. I tried searching for how the `class` keyword is implemented but can't seem to find anything. Just simply that "classes are functions". An explanation of what I am missing/misunderstanding is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for reading all this.

Comment: This is just a matter of syntax conventions. The constructor in a `class` definition, **is** the function that is called when using `new`. That's all. You should not interpret the claim of a class being a function as meaning that you can just replace the `class` keyword with the `function` keyword.

Comment: So then how should it be interpreted? A lot of sources say that classes are just functions in JavaScript but don't explain what they mean by that.

Comment: The *constructor* is the function that a class is. The methods defined are then just attached to the prototype. It's not a function that you *execute* and somehow has methods on it because that doesn't really make sense. `class Foo { constructor() {} method() {} }` is essentially the same as `function Foo() {} Foo.prototype.method = function() {}`. Which the article already explained.

Comment: @VLAZ Does it have to do with the fact that JavaScript is an interpreted language? I am reading that an interpreted language "is one where the instructions are not directly executed by the target machine, but instead, read and executed by some other program". So I suppose the interpreter reads `class Foo { constructor() {} method() {} }` and just interprets it as `function Foo() {} Foo.prototype.method = function() {}`?

Comment: @journeywithjavascript not really related. It's just syntax sugar. You can have syntax sugar in either interpreted or compiled languages.

Comment: @VLAZ I guess I'm still confused by the notion then that "classes are just functions". They seem fundamentally different. You can execute a function but not a class right? So why would one say that classes are functions? I get that the two examples you gave are equivalent - they are two ways of *doing* the same thing. But they are not the same thing right? For example "1" and 1 are equivalent, but they are not the same. A string is not a number, in the same way, it seems to me, a class is not a function. A class to me is a template for an object, not something to execute like a function.

Comment: @VLAZ in the same way that MDN has a step by step description of exactly what happens when you use the `new` keyword with a function (that I included in the question), do you know if they have a step by step description of exactly what happens when you use the `new` keyword with a class? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: "*You can execute a function but not a class right?*" yes, you can only execute a class constructor with `new`. That's the majority of differences between a class and a regular function. That's only there to prevent usage like `Foo()` without using `new` because it leads to more confusing semantics. "*it seems to me, a class is not a function*" then try `typeof (class Foo{})` and see what you get. Again classes are just syntactic sugar over regular JS mechanisms which is prototype inheritance.

Comment: "*do you know if they have a step by step description of exactly what happens when you use the new keyword with a class?*" it's the same thing. The constructor is executed and the same things happen. `new` is not two different things. There is *one* keyword `new` which works with functions.

Comment: I think I found an explanation on MDN:
"When a class declaration or class expression is evaluated, its various components are evaluated in the following order:

1. [...] 
2. *The constructor method is extracted, substituted with a default implementation if constructor is not present.*
[...]
7. The class is now fully initialized and can be used as a constructor function.

So it seems what follows a class declaration is evaluated - not executed. I take step 2. to mean that the constructor that is "extracted" effectively replaces the class - and that is how the class becomes a constructor

Comment: I think that's the explanation I'm looking for - the class keyword acts as an operator and what follows it is evaluated to a constructor, not executed as is.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419713/are-es6-classes-just-syntactic-sugar-for-the-prototypal-pattern-in-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74118473/classes-vs-prototypes-in-javascript/

Comment: @Bergi this is informative, thank you. The statement "In the background a class declaration or a class expression will create a constructor function with the same name as the class" supports my understanding. It's not that *class declarations themselves are functions to be executed as constructors*, but rather they are like an expression that is *evaluated behind the scenes to a constructor function*. The key point being there is some transformation that happens between the class declaration and the resulting constructor function.

Comment: @journeywithjavascript Well there's always a transformation when the interpreter instantiates a declaration or evaluates an expression: from code to runtime object :-) This is true for both functions and classes. The objects may behave slightly different in details, but in both cases you end up with a constructor function and a prototype object, which reference each other via `.prototype` and `.constructor` respectively, with the function stored in the variable with the given name, on which you can use the `new` operator to create an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and functions are the primary ways to define objects and their behavior in JavaScript. Let me explain how they work and their differences in terms of usage:

Functions (before ES6):

- Used to define "templates" for objects.
- Can be called directly to
  perform tasks.
- When used with the new keyword, they act as
  constructors for objects.
- Methods are added to the prototype, so all
  created objects share the same methods, saving memory.

```js
function Car(make) {
  this.make = make;
}

Car.prototype.displayMake = function() {
  return 'The make is ' + this.make;
};

var myCar = new Car('Toyota');
console.log(myCar.displayMake()); // "The make is Toyota"
```

Classes (ES6 and onwards):

- They are syntactic sugar over JavaScript's prototype functionality;
  they do the same job but with a cleaner syntax.
- Cannot be called
  without new.
- Have a constructor method to initialize the object.
- Methods defined within the class automatically go to the prototype.

```js
class Car {
  constructor(make) {
    this.make = make;
  }

  displayMake() {
    return `The make is ${this.make}`;
  }
}

const myCar = new Car('Toyota');
console.log(myCar.displayMake()); // "The make is Toyota"
```

Main differences:

- Syntax: Classes have a clearer and more understandable syntax,
  especially for people coming from other programming languages.
- Usage
  of this: With constructor functions, if you forget to use new, this
  will refer to the global object (in browsers, window), which is
  usually a mistake. With classes, if you try to call the class without
  new, JavaScript will throw an error.
- Hoisting: Functions in
  JavaScript are "hoisted," meaning you can reference them before they
  are defined in the code. Classes, however, are not hoisted, and you
  must define them before you can instantiate them.
- Static Methods:
  Classes allow you to define static methods with the static keyword,
  which are methods you can call on the class itself, not on an
  instance of the class. Classes in JavaScript simplify the definition
  of complex structures and inheritance, making them more accessible
  and manageable, especially for developers experienced with
  object-oriented languages.

Comment: Classes are also hoisted. Same mechanism as `const` and `let` [Are variables declared with let or const hoisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420) because using a class before definition still leads to [the temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone).

Comment: Functions can also define static methods. It's not as pretty but the `static` keyword is still just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yes, classes are also built in JavaScript. This means that the declaration of a class is moved to the top of its scope during the compilation phase, even though the code for the class may appear later in the script. Hoisting allows you to use a class before declaring it, but that doesn't mean the class is fully initialized at that point.

Comment: @JuanManuelGarciaMontealegre ... _"especially for developers experienced with object-oriented languages."_ ... should be _" ... especially for developers experienced with class based languages."_ since JavaScript is a multiparadigmatic PL which covers every aspect of how OO is defined (class syntax / class concept are by no means an essential part of OO).

Comment: @JuanManuelGarciaMontealegre thank you for taking the time to answer. I believe the explanation I was looking for was found on MDN, and reinforced by the threads Bergi linked in the comments. The explanation being it's not that class declarations themselves are functions to be executed as constructors, but rather they are like an expression that is evaluated behind the scenes to a constructor function. The key point being there is some transformation that happens between the class declaration and the resulting constructor function