# Sort a Table based on the option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, jquery-mobile

Good day people,
so i have a **jquery mobile** page like that:

```
<div id="testTableDiv" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 250px">
<table class="ui-responsive ui-shadow gk-decorate table-stripe" id="testTable" is="jqm-table" data-role="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <th>Numbers</th>
      <th>Names</th>
      <th>Countries</th>
      <th>Animals</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   .
   .
   content see Fiddle
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<select id="selectId">
  <option selected disabled>Choose Sort View</option>
  <option>Names, Animals, Countries</option>
  <option>Numbers, Fruits, Names</option>
  <option>Countries, Numbers, Animales</option>
</select>
```

And based on the Selected option from the select menu i can filter that Table. Take a look at my snippet

```js
function changeOrder(table, from, to) {
      var rows = jQuery('tr', table);
      var cols;
      rows.each(function () {
        cols = jQuery(this).children('th, td');

        if (to < cols.length)
          cols.eq(from).detach().insertBefore(cols.eq(to));
        else
          cols.eq(from).detach().insertAfter(cols.last());
      });
    }
    
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#testTable').data('origin-table', $('#testTable').html()).text();

  $("body").on("change", "#selectId", function() {

    if ($("#selectId option:selected").text() == "Names, Animals, Countries") {
    
      $('#testTable').html($('#testTable').data('origin-table'));
      var myTable = document.getElementById("testTable");

      changeOrder(myTable,2,0);
      changeOrder(myTable,4,1);
      changeOrder(myTable,4,2);
      
      $('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();
   $('td:nth-child(5),th:nth-child(5)').hide();

    }
    if ($("#selectId option:selected").text() == "Numbers, Fruits, Names") {
      $('#testTable').html($('#testTable').data('origin-table'));
      var myTable = document.getElementById("testTable");

      changeOrder(myTable,1,0);
      
      $('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();
   $('td:nth-child(5),th:nth-child(5)').hide();
    }
    
     if ($("#selectId option:selected").text() == "Countries, Numbers, Animales") {
      $('#testTable').html($('#testTable').data('origin-table'));
      var myTable = document.getElementById("testTable");

      changeOrder(myTable,3,0);
      changeOrder(myTable,2,1);
      changeOrder(myTable,5,0);
      
      $('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();
   $('td:nth-child(5),th:nth-child(5)').hide();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.css">

<div id="testTableDiv" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 250px">
<table class="ui-responsive ui-shadow gk-decorate table-stripe" id="testTable" is="jqm-table" data-role="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <th>Numbers</th>
      <th>Names</th>
      <th>Countries</th>
      <th>Animals</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>2321</td>
      <td>Kate</td>
      <td>France</td>
      <td>Tiger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>819</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
      <td>Cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>728</td>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Spain</td>
      <td>Lion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Charlie</td>
      <td>Croatia</td>
      <td>Turtle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>Ben</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td>Bee</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<select id="selectId">
  <option selected disabled>Choose Sort View</option>
  <option>Names, Animals, Countries</option>
  <option>Numbers, Fruits, Names</option>
  <option>Countries, Numbers, Animales</option>
</select>
```

---

Now i also want to sort that Table based on the first Column that will be shown.
For example: When the user selectes the `"Countires, Numbers, Animals"` Select option i want to sort the table after the Countries like that:

```
Croatia     11     Mango
France      2321   Banana 
Italy       62     Orange
Japan       42     Cherry
Mexico      819    Apple
Spain       728    Banana
```

The content gets added dynamically: But i have a array for each column like:
`countryArray[..]<br>numberArray[..]<br>...`
 And i can already sort that array with the javascript method `.sort()`

 **Now comes my question how can i apply those sort changes onto my table? The column connection should of course still be available.**

Comment: Sort the json before creating your table...

Comment: Then no sort. Once the DOM is created, you need to extract the data from the table using jquery, sort them, and rewrite the DOM table element.

Comment: This is very bad code. Extract your table with a loop into an array containing the elements. Sort them and rewrite the dom. 5 codes lines at most

Comment: Javasscript is all about elements. If you dont learn to use it = no future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem with the answer from [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417685/alexander) from this question here: 
[Sorting multiple arrays at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960105/sorting-multiple-arrays-at-once).
What i did was: Since i got the Table content from each column in a array i simply ordered the appropriate array and adjust the others arrays to it. After that is done i just update my Table using the `innerText` method.