# What does this code do(Sorting Multiple Arrays)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was searching for "how to sort multiple arrays at once" and found this question here: 
[Sorting multiple arrays at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960105/sorting-multiple-arrays-at-once)
And there a nice answer from Alexander solving my problem. But I don't fully understand this part from the answer right there:

```
/* A shorthand function */
var comparator = function(arr) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return ((arr[a] < arr[b]) ? -1 : ((arr[a] > arr[b]) ? 1 : 0));
    };
};
```

Could someone explain me what this part of his code does?

Comment: It's comparing values in the array passed in and returning a -1 if the next element is great than the current and a 1 if the current is greater than the next, otherwise returns a 0 if their equal.

Comment: Also, look up ternary operators for the syntax for the last return statement.

Comment: It takes an array and returns a function, when invoked by two index arguments you get a comparison value of the items at those indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will compare the values of 2 indexes of an array.  The return uses a syntax called [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).  Here is a nice link that explains it.

[Question Mark in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

It is sorting an array of indices by the respective values in `arr`. To be exact, `comparator` takes an array and returns a closure function that can be used to compare two index numbers with each other, by looking up the values at these indices in the `arr` and comparing them.