# How can I sort data from highest to lowest in chart.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts, chart.js

I'm having some sort of problems regarding on how to sort your data highest to lowest using chart.js? I was using laravel and I used chart.js to display my data, However I don't have any idea how to make an operation to sort my highest value to lowest value (data) in chart.js

**My code**

```
var ctx_1 = document.getElementById('non_200_pages').getContext('2d');
var myChart_1 = new Chart(ctx_1, {
type: 'horizontalBar',
data: {
    labels: ["Total","301 Redirect","Broken Pages (4xx Errors)","Uncategorised HTTP Response Codes","5xx Errors","Unauthorised Pages","Non-301 Redirects"],
    datasets: [{

        data: [ {{ $array_non_200_pages[0] }}, {{ $array_non_200_pages[1] }}, {{ $array_non_200_pages[2] }}, {{ $array_non_200_pages[3] }}, {{ $array_non_200_pages[4] }}, {{ $array_non_200_pages[5] }}, {{ $array_non_200_pages[6]}} ],
        backgroundColor: [ 
            'rgba(237, 56, 98, 1.0)',
            'rgba(237, 56, 98, 1.0)',
            'rgba(237, 56, 98, 1.0)',
            'rgba(237, 56, 98, 1.0)',
            'rgba(237, 56, 98, 1.0)',
            'rgba(237, 56, 98, 1.0)',
            'rgba(237, 56, 98, 1.0)'
        ]

    }]
},
options: {
    showAllTooltips: true,
    tooltips: {
          enabled: true,
          displayColors: false,
          yPadding: 20,
          xPadding: 30,
          caretSize: 10,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 1)',
          bodyFontSize: 16,
          bodyFontColor: 'rgb(50, 50, 50)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          cornerRadius: 0,
          yAlign: 'bottom',
          xAlign: 'center',
          position: 'custom',
          custom: function(tooltip) {
            if (!tooltip) return;
            // disable displaying the color box;
            tooltip.displayColors = false;
          },
          callbacks: {
            // use label callback to return the desired label
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return tooltipItem.yLabel + " : " + tooltipItem.xLabel ;
            },
            // remove title
            title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return;
            }
        }
    },
    responsive: false,
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            },
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                stepSize:5,
                display: false
            },
            gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
            }
        }],
    },
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
    align: 'end',
    anchor: 'end',        
    backgroundColor: function(context) {
      return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
    },
    borderRadius: 4,
    color: 'white',
    formatter: Math.round
  }
}
}
});
```

**My Output**
[image: My work]

**My Expected Output**
[image: Expected work]

Base on the picture I want my total just like that and have a value of `{{$array_non_200_pages[0] }}`  Now the problem is I need to sort the following data to make it highest to lowest. How can I do that? Is there someone can help me or guide me the best way to resolve my problem? Sorry for my bad English. Thank you so much

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how you can merge and sort data and labels together.
first sort them then assign `newArrayData` to data property and `newArrayLabel` to labels property of your config object.

```js
arrayLabel = ["Total", "301 Redirect", "Broken Pages (4xx Errors)", "Uncategorised HTTP Response Codes", "5xx Errors", "Unauthorised Pages", "Non-301 Redirects"]

arrayData = [16, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0, 1];

arrayOfObj = arrayLabel.map(function(d, i) {
  return {
    label: d,
    data: arrayData[i] || 0
  };
});

sortedArrayOfObj = arrayOfObj.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.data>a.data;
});

newArrayLabel = [];
newArrayData = [];
sortedArrayOfObj.forEach(function(d){
  newArrayLabel.push(d.label);
  newArrayData.push(d.data);
});

console.log(newArrayLabel);
console.log(newArrayData);
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thank you so much

Comment: Hello, this script works in Firefox but does not work in Google Chrome.

Comment: The reason why it works on Firefox but not Chrome is sort method.  Please use standard way to sort. `return b.data - a.data;` instead of `return b.data>a.data;`

Comment: return b.data - a.data; dont work for me. @QingfeiYuan

Comment: I used this thread about sorting two arrays given values for one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499268/sort-two-arrays-the-same-way.