# How to set value of bars in descending order in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to set the values of bars in descending order. First way is to make a key value pair like passing company name along with value and then sort them. But the issue is I am sending an array of 10 companies as label and then array of 10 companies as data. I dont know how to send them as object of array and sort it. or is there any other way to do it in chart js. A

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Sarmaaya Charts</title>

</head>
<style>
    body {
        color: rgb(177, 177, 177) !important;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container m-3  ">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12  bg-white">
                <h6 class=" ">Top Points Contributor </h6>
                <hr width="100%">
                <canvas id="topContributor"></canvas>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-R/QOHLpV1Ggq22vfDAWYOaMd5RopHrJNMxi8/lJu8Oihwi4Ho4BRFeiMiCefn9rasajKjnx9/fTQ/xkWnkDACg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

    <script>
        Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

        function createChart(topGainersNames, topGainersChange, topLosersNames, topLosersChange) {
            return {
                labels: chartLabels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: topGainersNames,
                        //label: ['FFC', 'CCF', 'DFG', 'FFC', 'MTL', 'SYS', 'INDU', 'ACLU', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'EFl', 'LMK'],
                        data: topGainersChange,
                        backgroundColor: '#2FC798',
                        borderColor: '#2FC798',
                        datalabels: {
                            align: 'top',
                            anchor: 'end',
                            offset: 4,
                            color: '#2FC798',

                        },

                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: topLosersNames,
                        data: topLosersChange,
                        backgroundColor: '#C72151',
                        borderColor: '#C72151',
                        datalabels: {
                            align: 'bottom',
                            anchor: 'end',
                            offset: 4,
                            color: '#C72151',


                        },

                    },

                ],

            }

        }

        function chartStyling() {

            return {
                animation: {
                    duration: 500,
                },
                responsive: true,

                interaction: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                layout: {
                    padding: 20
                },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        hoverRadius: 6
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    tooltip: {
                        caretSize: 10,
                        yAlign: 'bottom',
                        caretPadding: 50,
                        padding: 10,
                        position: 'nearest',
                        mode: 'nearest',
                        intersect: false,
                        enabled: true,
                        borderWidth: 20,
                        intersect: true,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(92, 89, 89)',
                        callbacks: {
                            /*label: function (context) {
                                //console.log('aa', context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex])
                                //return context.dataset.label[context.dataIndex] + '\n' +
                                //  context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];

                                //return `${context.dataset.label[context.dataIndex]} \n Index Point : 15.45 \n Weight :0.68% \n Market Cap : Rs. 12,79,90,000 \n  %  Px Chg : 5.55% \n`
                                return `(${context.dataset.label[context.dataIndex]} + "/n" + 'rs').split('\n')`;
                            },*/
                            label: function (context) {
                                return context.dataset.label[context.dataIndex];
                            },
                            afterLabel: function (context) {
                                var someValue2 = "\nIndex Point: \nWeight: \nMarket Cap: \n% Px Chg: ";
                                return someValue2;
                            }

                        }

                    },
                    elements: {
                        point: {
                            pointStyle: 'rect'
                        }

                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        position: 'top',
                        align: 'end',
                        labels: {
                            boxWidth: 5,
                            usePointStyle: true,
                        }

                    },
                    datalabels: {
                        display: true,
                        borderWidth: 0.5,
                        color: 'black',
                        formatter: function (value, context) {
                            //console.log(context.dataset.label)
                            return context.dataset.label[context.dataIndex] + '\n' + 'Rs ' + value

                        },
                        font: {
                            size: 10,
                            weight: 'bold',

                        }

                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        display: false,
                        stacked: true,
                        grid: {
                            display: false,
                            lineWidth: 3

                        },
                    },
                    x: {
                        stacked: true,
                        display: false,
                        grid: {
                            display: false,
                        },

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        chartLabels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("market_symbol", "KSE100");
        var sam;
        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formdata,
            redirect: 'follow',
        };

        var topGainers = [18.32, 12.37, 11.37, 10.22, 9.45, 8.98, 8.76, 7.34, 6.4, 5.21, 4.32, 3.22]
        var topLosers = [-8.32, -7.37, -6.37, -5.39, -5.37, -4.37, -4.19, -3.77, -3.12, -2.98, -2.34, -2.19]

        fetch("https://dev-api.sarmaaya.pk/3.0/view_market_performers.php", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => apiData(data)

            ).catch(error =>
                console.log('error', error)
            );
        const apiData = (data) => {
            var topGainersNames = []
            var topLosersNames = []
            var topGainersChange = []
            var topLosersChange = []
            for (var i = 0; i < data.gainers.length; i++) {
                topGainersNames.push(data.gainers[i].stock_symbol)
                topLosersNames.push(data.losers[i].stock_symbol)
                topGainersChange.push(data.gainers[i].stock_change)
                topLosersChange.push(data.losers[i].stock_change)

            }
            console.log('topGainersNames', topGainersNames)
            console.log('topGainersChange', topGainersChange)
            console.log('topLosersNames', topLosersNames)
            console.log('topLosersChange', topLosersChange)
            var ctx = document.getElementById('topContributor').getContext('2d');

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                data: createChart(topGainersNames, topGainersChange, topLosersNames, topLosersChange),
                options: chartStyling()
            })
        }


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also the jsfiddle link is this. https://jsfiddle.net/a794b3wv/

Comment: Are you trying to to this: [How can I sort data from highest to lowest in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785769/how-can-i-sort-data-from-highest-to-lowest-in-chart-js)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying this one, but the issue is if I sort the array then the labels dont match.

Comment: yes, It worked. I have one more question I want to display data from API to the tooltip. data includes, stock title, indexpoints, weightage, marketcap, stock_change_p. Now I dont know how to pass these arrays to the tooltip and show exactly yhe one I am hovering over. heres the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/90871gaz/