# Sort an array on the basis of another array in javascript

Tags: javascript

These are my two arrays.
I want sizeIdArray to get sorted on the basis of sizesNameArray.
For Example,

```
sizeIdArray = [1, 2, 3];
sizeNameArray = [2.5m, 8m, 3.5m];
```

After sorting sizeNameArray,

```
sizeNameArray = [2.5m, 3.5m, 8m];
```

and

```
sizeIdArray should be [1, 3, 2];
```

How do i attain this?
I was able to obtain the sizeNameArray by this method.

```
sizesNameArray.sort(function(a,b){return parseFloat(a.replace('#', ''))-parseFloat(b.replace('#', ''))})
```

replace function is if there was '#' in front.

Sorry if i am not clear with my question.
I want to sort both at the same time, but sizeIdArray should be sorted according to sizeNameArray.

Please help. Thank You

Comment: what is the meaning of `'m'`? million?

Comment: metre, but it doesnt matter here, i think!!

Comment: Maybe this will help a bit https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/rNewmyx

Comment: Assuming that "m" (or any other trailing character) should not have any influence on the sorting, you can do it with the following one-liner: `sizeNameArray.map((c,i)=>[i,c]).sort((a,b)=>parseFloat(a[1])-parseFloat(b[1])).map(e=>sizeIdArray[e[0]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
sizeIdArray = [1, 2, 3];
sizeNameArray = ['2.5m', '8m', '3.5m'];

//1) combine the arrays:
var list = [];
for (var j = 0; j < sizeNameArray.length; j++) 
    list.push({'sizeId': sizeIdArray[j], 'sizeName': sizeNameArray[j]});

//2) sort:
list.sort(function(a, b) {
    return ((a.sizeName.replace('#', '') < b.sizeName.replace('#', '')) ? -1 
            : ((a.sizeName.replace('#', '') == b.sizeName.replace('#', '')) ? 0 : 1));
    //Sort could be modified too, for example sort on the id if the name is the same.
});

//3) separate them back out:
for (var k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    sizeNameArray[k] = list[k].sizeName;
    sizeIdArray[k] = list[k].sizeId;
}

console.log(sizeIdArray);
console.log(sizeNameArray);
```

Refer [Sort two arrays the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499268/sort-two-arrays-the-same-way)

Answer (score 1):

Heres more general approach, no need of any parsefloat.

```js
sizeIdArray = [1, 2, 3];
sizeNameArray = ['2.5m', '8m', '3.5m'];
var m = {}
for(let i in sizeNameArray){
   m[sizeNameArray[i]] = sizeIdArray[i]
}


Object.keys(m).sort().forEach((item,index)=>sizeIdArray[index] = m[item])
console.log(sizeIdArray)
```

Comment: It will produce the result `['2,1,3]` when you have input like `['2.5m', '10m', '3.5m']`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the perfect solution but if time complexity is not a concern, you can use this algorithm. It's sorting it manually by finding the smallest number in each iteration and swapping it. But, when you swap the `sizeNameArray` you also swap the `sizeIdArray` and hence you will get the result needed. To make it more optimal you can refer to this [Sort an Array based on Another Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-array-according-order-defined-another-array/)

```js
sizeIdArray = [1, 2, 3];
sizeNameArray = [2.5, 8, 3.5];

for(let i = 0; i < sizeNameArray.length; i++) {
  let smallest = i;
  for(let j = i; j < sizeNameArray.length; j++) {
    if(sizeNameArray[j] < sizeNameArray[smallest])
      smallest = j;
  }
  let temp = sizeNameArray[i];
  sizeNameArray[i] = sizeNameArray[smallest];
  sizeNameArray[smallest] = temp;
  
  temp = sizeIdArray[i];
  sizeIdArray[i] = sizeIdArray[smallest];
  sizeIdArray[smallest] = temp;
}

console.log(sizeIdArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.

```
var done = false;
      while (!done) {
        done = true;
        for (var i = 1; i < sizesNameArray.length; i += 1) {
          if (parseFloat(sizesNameArray[i - 1].replace('#', '')) > parseFloat(sizesNameArray[i].replace('#', ''))) {
            done = false;
            var tmp = sizesNameArray[i - 1];
            var tmp2 = sizeIdArray[i-1];
            sizesNameArray[i - 1] = sizesNameArray[i];
            sizeIdArray[i - 1] = sizeIdArray[i];
            sizesNameArray[i] = tmp;
            sizeIdArray[i] = tmp2;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: What about this, is it not efficient?