# change index in one array in accordance with another one js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to change indexes of elements in arr a due to their indexes in arr b.

```
const a = [4,3,2,1,5];
const b = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(a)  [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort two arrays the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499268/sort-two-arrays-the-same-way)

Comment: so in your case does both arrays become the same in the end

Comment: @cmgchess, yes, but its a simple example. they are arrays of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean ordering array `a` according to array `b`, then you can do like this:

```
a.forEach((element,i) => {
    // first get the index of a[i] from array b
    const index = b.indexOf(a[i])
    
    // then swap them
    const temp = a[index];
    a[index] = a[i];
    a[i] = temp;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by using the other array as index. If this daoes not work with real data, please andd a small amount of data to highlight the problem.

```js
const
    a = [4, 3, 2, 1, 5],
    b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

a.sort((l, r) => b[l - 1] - b[r - 1]);

console.log(...a);
```